# Marriages in infinite bipartite graphs with many neighbors

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $A,B\neq \emptyset$ be disjoint and suppose $G = (A\cup B, E)$ is bipartite where for all $e\in E$ we have $e\cap A \neq \emptyset\neq e\cap B$. For $a\in A$ we set $N_G(a) = \{b\in B: (\exists e\in E)\{a,b\}\in e\}$, and for $S\subseteq A$ let $N_G(S) = \bigcup\{N_G(a):a\in S\}$.

A *matching* is a set $M$ of pairwise disjoint edges, and a *marriage* of $A$ is a matching such that $A\subseteq \bigcup M$. For finite bipartite graphs, [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) says that there is a marriage if

> (Hall's condition:) for all $S\subseteq A$ we have $|S| \leq |N_G(S)|$.

**Question**. Assuming that we $|A|=|B| = \aleph_0$, is there $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:

> if $|N_G(a)| \geq n$ for all $a\in A$ and Hall's condition holds for $G$, then $G$ has a marriage

?

---

**Background**: For $n=1$, the implication in the question fails: Let $A = \omega \times\{0\}$ and $B = \omega \times\{1\}$. Set $$E = \big\{\{(k,0), (k-1,1)\}: k\in\omega\setminus\{0\}\big\}\cup\big\{\{(0,0),(n,1)\}: n\in\omega\big\}.$$ Then it is easy to see that $G= (A\cup B,E)$ obeys Hall's condition, but $G$ has no marriage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You may modify your example. Join $(k,0)$ with $(m,1)$ for all $m<k$ and also join $(k,0)$ with all $(m,1)$ for $k\leqslant n$. Then any matching must match $\{0,\dots,N\}\times 0$ with $\{0,\dots,N-1\}\times 1$ for large enough $N$. This is impossible.

Comment: I like your construction. However, it seems to me that the question was: whether for each bipartite graph there exists a positive integer with certain property, while the counterexample of you is like: for each positive integer there exists a counterexample.

Comment: @WeiWang I do not think so. Which certain property?

Comment: Sorry. I mistook the question.