# Maximality with respect to having no marriage

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, order-theory, posets, bipartite-graphs

Let $A,B\neq \emptyset$ be disjoint and suppose $G = (A\cup B, E)$ is bipartite where for all $e\in E$ we have $e\cap A \neq \emptyset\neq e\cap B$. For $a\in A$ we set $N_G(a) = \{b\in B: (\exists e\in E)\{a,b\}\in e\}$, and for $S\subseteq A$ let $N_G(S) = \bigcup\{N_G(a):a\in S\}$.

A *matching* is a set $M$ of pairwise disjoint edges, and a *marriage* of $A$ is a matching such that $A\subseteq \bigcup M$. For finite bipartite graphs, [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) says that there is a marriage if

> (Hall's condition:) for all $S\subseteq A$ we have $|S| \leq |N_G(S)|$.

Let $A,B$ be infinite and disjoint and set $[A,B]_2 = \big\{\{a,b\}: a\in A, b\in B\big\}$. Consider the collection ${\cal E}$ of sets $E\subseteq [A,B]_2$ such that Hall's condition holds for $(A\cup B,E)$, but $(A\cup B,E)$ has no marriage.

**Question.** Does every element of the poset $({\cal E},\subseteq)$ lie below a maximal element?

Comment: I must be missing something. The theorem says there is a marriage if Hall's condition holds. You are asking for Hall's condition to hold, but for there to be no marriage.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the theorem is for finite graphs, for infinite graphs Hall's condition is not sufficient, see examples here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271254/marriages-in-infinite-bipartite-graphs-with-many-neighbors?rq=1

Comment: by the way, if the infinite graph does not satisfy Hall's condition, it of course is contained in a maximal graph without marriage. So, the question remains essentially the same if you simply ask whether any graph without marriage has a maximal over-graph without marriage.